# i am a beginner in python can someone help me understand this?

Tags: python-3.x

[Picture of the code. There is an explanation in the book but i couldn't keep up. Maybe someone can explain this better. Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVByO.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy-paste the relevant code with proper formatting rather than linking to an image. Describe what you understand, and what you don't. Provide the original explanation, and point out the unclear parts. Choose a specific title the summarizes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it about the python function example.
In your pic, it has 2 functions:

1. print_models: print item of list para 1 and append to list param 2.
2. show_complete_models: print all item of list input

In function **print_models**, you can input a parameter, do something and store the result to second parameter.